# Google Charts - Tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am trying to add a tooltip to a Time chart, however am experiencing very strange results:

```
var container = document.getElementById('example2.1');
var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();


dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
dataTable.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
```

Do some dynamic stuff here and loop through:

```
dataTable.addRow([$(this).attr('ows_Title'),start,end,"Status: " + $(this).attr("ows_Status")]);

chart.draw(dataTable);
```

The chart populates perfectly, except NO tooltip!

Anyone have any ideas? Attached is my result!

Here is an image:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check on documentation, html tooltip for Timeline is not supported:

[supported_charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#supported_charts%20supported_charts)

However, you could make a workaround using onmouseover event listener and setting the tooltip according to the `e.row` value. Here is a simple example:

```
function myHandler(e){
        if(e.row != null){
            $(".google-visualization-tooltip").html(dataTable.getValue(e.row,3)).css({width:"auto",height:"auto"});
        }        
    }

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', myHandler);
```

Full example : http://jsfiddle.net/s9g99pqk/1/

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
dataTable.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
```

it should be:

```
dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {'html': true}});
```

Comment: I did this but no success!